# SHOW COLUMNS Command for HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

Is there an HSQLDB equivalent for the MYSQL SHOW COLUMNS from TABLE command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HSQLDB does not have separate commands for showing tables, columns or other database objects.

You use `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and various other tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for such purposes.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_information_schema

Answer (score 2):

This is the query that you need.

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your schema>' AND TABLE_NAME = '<name table or view>';`